# Covariant derivative

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

[image]

Hi, Could you explain to me why the subtraction of  vector at some point  and parallel transported vector is covariant derivative vector. How is it possible

Answer (score 1):

Consider some path $\gamma^{\mu}(\tau)$, and some vector $x^{\mu}$.  Parallel transport is the condition when $\gamma^{a}\nabla_{a}x^{b} = 0$

Torsion is present if, for two paths $\gamma^{a}$ and $\delta^{a}$ that satisfy $\partial_{a}\gamma^{b} = \partial_{a}\delta^{b} = 0$, it is the case that parallel transport of $\gamma$ along $\delta$ produces a different result from parallel transporting $\delta$ along $\gamma$, since:

$$\gamma^{a}\nabla_{a}\delta^{b} = \gamma^{a}\partial_{a}\delta^{b} + \gamma^{a}\Gamma_{ac}{}^{b}\delta^{c}$$

and

$$\delta^{a}\nabla_{a}\gamma^{b} = \delta^{a}\partial_{a}\gamma^{b} + \delta^{a}\Gamma_{ac}{}^{b}\gamma^{c}$$

and therefore:

$$\gamma^{a}\nabla_{a}\delta^{b} - \delta^{a}\nabla_{a}\gamma^{b}  = \gamma^{a}\delta^{c}(\Gamma_{ac}{}^{b} - \Gamma_{ca}{}^{b}) = \gamma^{a}\delta^{c}T_{ac}{}^{b}$$